# Java, map a list and do a contains check in one line or iterate over the entire list?

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list of employees. Each employee has an unique identifier `id`. I have an `employeeId` and have to check whether the employee represented by the `employeeid` is inside the list. There are two ways i can think of doing it, which of them is better. Is there a performance difference?

1)

```
if (employees.stream().map(Employee::getId).collect(Collectors.toList()).contains(employeeId)) {
  // do something
}
```

2)

```
boolean employeeIsInsideTheList = false;
 for (Employee employee : employees) {
   if (employee.getId() == employeeId) {
      employeeIsInsideTheList = true;
    }
 }
if(employeeIsInsideTheList) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: You've got a potential issue with the line `employee.getId() == employeeId`. You should probably be using `.equals` here

Comment: The id is a long, not a String.

Comment: I reckon the only advantage of using stream over the normal for-each is that, you can iterate and do any filtering on the collection in parallel.

Comment: What are the criteria you use to decide which is better? The one that takes less time to complete? The one that uses less resources?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `Stream` version defeats the purpose of `Stream`s, since it doesn't take advantage of lazy evaluation and short circuiting. You are doing two full iterations - the first to transform the `List` of Employees to a `List` of IDs, and the second to search for a specific ID in the `List` of IDs (via the `contains()` method).

A better solution would be to search for a matching ID without building a `List` of IDs:

```
if (employees.stream().anyMatch(e -> e.getId().equals(employeeId)))) {
  // do something
}
```

Your `for` loop solution can be similarly improved by breaking out of the loop once a matching identifier is found.

After the improvements, whether or not there is a performance difference is meaningless if the `List` is relatively small. I'd prefer the `Stream`s version, which is shorter and more readable.

If the `List` is large, and performance is an issue, I suggest you measure the performance of both solutions to find out which one if faster.

Comment: Or `emp.stream().map(Employee::getId).anyMatch(employeeId::equals)`. I still haven't decided what I prefer.

Comment: @daniu that one is nice if you prefer method references over lambda expressions. On the other hand, it has an additional `Stream` operation.